# Connect Android devices via (ethernet) cable

Tags: networking

I want to assign static IP Addresses to my Android devices, and connect them via say Ethernet cable.

Essentially create a network by connecting android devices using physical wires and have IP addresses work.

The idea is to allow android devices to communicate to one another using the IP the addresses over this network. (There is no wifi in this solution.)

Is this possible?

Comment: No, this is not possible just with Android devices and USB.  You need something to handle the routing and act as the host, and USB is a tree structure.